# Mouseenter event is skipping elements

Tags: javascript, angular, mouseenter

I have this directive to do something when the `mouseenter` event is triggered on an element. But when I drag the mouse fast, over the elements some elements are getting skipped without triggering the `mouseenter` event.

I actually want to highlight a range of cells of a grid when the mouse moves. I have added this directive to the template of the grid cell.

```
@Directive({
  // tslint:disable-next-line:directive-selector
  selector: '[appRangeSelector]'
})
export class RangeSelectorDirective {

   @Input() public selectorParams: any;

   public isSelected = false;

   constructor(private elRef: ElementRef,
       private renderer: Renderer2) { }

   @HostListener('mouseenter', ['$event']) public onMouseEnter(e) {
       if (e.buttons === 1 || e.buttons === 3) {

           if (!this.isSelected) {
               console.log('selected');
               this.renderer.setStyle(this.elRef.nativeElement, 'background', 'blue');
               this.isSelected = true;
           } else {
               console.log('deselected');
               this.renderer.setStyle(this.elRef.nativeElement, 'background', 'unset');
               this.isSelected = false;
           }

       }
   }

}
```

I need to select the range when the user select the cell range in any speed.
Any help about this is appreciated.

Comment: That is not necessarily a thing you can do anything about in the first place … if the browser simply doesn’t _fire_ the event above a certain speed, due to whatever limitations (physical, electronic, throttling for performance, ...), then there’s little you can do about that. If you only need a selection in a “line” in one direction, or of a solid rectangle, then you could think about alternatives like seeing where the mouse cursor comes to rest for a little longer, to get a start and end “coordinate”, which would allow you to then consider all cells in between those as marked.

Comment: Is listening to `mouseover` an option? [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseenter) claims that sometimes it may be beneficial for performance reasons

Comment: why not using the native event from Angular instead of adding a listener?

Answer (score 2):

Operating system only update mouse position at a certain interval, and continuous movement is not garanteed.

If you want to be bulletproof, you might need to listen to mousemove event, calculate trajectory, and check if it intersect with any of your element.
However, I'm afraid that this can be somewhat heavy, so you better benchmark it first.