# Async capture of mouseover/mousedown events (angular/typescript)

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, mouseevent

I'm trying to run an event each mousedown or or drag (mousedown + mouseover) in a table.

However, if the user scrolls at even a moderate pace, some mouseover events are not captured using the native angular mouseover/mouseenter.

Is there a best way to capture the mouseover events and run a process asynchronously?

Attached is a stackblitz with an example.  However, if you mousedown in the grid and mouseover other cells, you'll notice that sometimes cells do not highlight.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pbu1vx

Component:

```
 <table (mouseleave)="down = false">
      <TR *ngFor="let row of numRows; let i = index">
        <TD class="cellStyle noSelect"
            [class.isHighlighted]="row.isHighlighted === true"
            (mousedown)="gridMouseDown(i)"
            (mouseover)="gridMouseOver(i)"
            (mouseup)="down = false;"
        >&nbsp;
        </TD>
      </TR>
    </table>
```

TS:

```
// dummy data for table
numRows = [
    {isHighlighted: false},
    {isHighlighted: false},
    {isHighlighted: false},
    {isHighlighted: false}
    ];

  // tracks if mouse is down
  down = false;

  async gridMouseDown(i) {
    this.down = true;
    // highlight/unhighlight cell and run asynchronous process 
    this.numRows[i].isHighlighted = !this.numRows[i].isHighlighted;
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(i)
    }, 1000)
  }

    async gridMouseOver(i) {
    if (this.down) {
      // if mousedown, highlight/unhighlight cell and run async process 
      this.numRows[i].isHighlighted = !this.numRows[i].isHighlighted;
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(i)
      }, 1000)
    }
  }
```

CSS:

```
.isHighlighted {
  background-color: blue !important;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mouseenter event is skipping elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53187329/mouseenter-event-is-skipping-elements)

Comment: @pascalpuetz  Thanks, but that does not have an accepted answer, and I'm using one of the suggestions (native mouseover rather than hostlisteners) and getting skips

Comment: Its the same problem - the browser does not even trigger those events.